# How to sort date array?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I want to sort array that is full of month with year, example:

```
["Nov 2019","Apr 2020","MAR 2018","Jan 2018","May 2018"]
```

(non sorted)

to :

```
["Jan 2018","Mar 2018","May 2018","Nov 2019","Apr 2020"]
```

(sorted) like this...

```
func sortDate( arr : inout [String]) {
    let months : [String] = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"]
    for i in 0..<arr.count{
        for j in i..<arr.count{
            let string1 = arr[i]
            let string2 = arr[j]
            let month1 = String(string1[string1.startIndex...string1.index(string1.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)])
            let month2 = String(string2[string2.startIndex...string2.index(string2.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)])
            if months.index(of: month1.lowercased())! > months.index(of: month2.lowercased())! {
                let temp = arr[i]
                arr[i] = arr[j]
                arr[j] = temp
            }
        }
    }
    for i in 0..<arr.count{
        for j in i..<arr.count{
            let string1 = arr[i]
            let string2 = arr[j]
            if (string1[string1.index(before: string1.endIndex)..<string1.endIndex] as NSString).intValue < (string2[string2.index(before: string2.endIndex)..<string2.endIndex] as NSString).intValue {
                let temp = arr[i]
                arr[i] = arr[j]
                arr[j] = temp
            }

        }
    }

}
```

This is what I tried but it's not working properly.

This is input:

```
["Jan 2020", "Feb 2018", "Mar 2018", "Apr 2018", "May 2018", "Jun 2018", "Jul 2018", "Aug 2018", "Sep 2018", "Oct 2018", "Nov 2018", "Jun 2019", "Feb 2019", "Jul 2019", "Apr 2019", "Aug 2019", "Sep 2019", "May 2019", "Oct 2019", "Jan 2019", "Mar 2019", "Nov 2019"]
```

Output is:

```
["Jan 2019", "Feb 2019", "Mar 2019", "Apr 2019", "May 2019", "Jun 2019", "Jul 2019", "Aug 2019", "Sep 2019", "Oct 2019", "Nov 2019", "Jul 2018", "Mar 2018", "May 2018", "Aug 2018", "Feb 2018", "Sep 2018", "Oct 2018", "Apr 2018", "Nov 2018", "Jun 2018", "Jan 2020"]
```

Comment: you can convert your date string to date and then you can sort your date array easily.

Comment: @chauhan i will try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably use a date formatter to parse these dates and then sort by that:

```
let input = ["Jan 2020", "Feb 2018", "Mar 2018", "Apr 2018", "May 2018", "Jun 2018", "Jul 2018", "Aug 2018", "Sep 2018", "Oct 2018", "Nov 2018", "Jun 2019", "Feb 2019", "Jul 2019", "Apr 2019", "Aug 2019", "Sep 2019", "May 2019", "Oct 2019", "Jan 2019", "Mar 2019", "Nov 2019"]
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "MMM yyyy"
let output = input.sorted { string1, string2 in
    guard let date1 = formatter.date(from: string1) else { return true }
    guard let date2 = formatter.date(from: string2) else { return false }
    return date1 < date2
}
```

Or, if you've got a lot of strings and you want to eliminate redundant formatter conversions:

```
let output = input
    .map { (string: $0, date: formatter.date(from: $0)) }
    .sorted {
        guard let date1 = $0.date else { return true }
        guard let date2 = $1.date else { return false }
        return date1 < date2
    }.map { $0.string }
```

Comment: Nitpicking: The comparator is not a "strict weak ordering", it returns true if string1==string2 is invalid (violates the irreflexivity) :) Changing the order of the 2 guard statements should fix that.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this answer with us. It helps me a lot

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
let dateStringArray = ["Jan 2020", "Feb 2018", "Mar 2018", "Apr 2018", "May 2018", "Jun 2018", "Jul 2018", "Aug 2018", "Sep 2018", "Oct 2018", "Nov 2018", "Jun 2019", "Feb 2019", "Jul 2019", "Apr 2019", "Aug 2019", "Sep 2019", "May 2019", "Oct 2019", "Jan 2019", "Mar 2019", "Nov 2019"]
var dateArray = [Date]()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM yyyy"

for dateString in dateStringArray{
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
    if let convertedDate = date{
        dateArray.append(convertedDate)
    }
}

for date in dateArray.sorted(by: {$0 < $1}){
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    print(dateString)
}
```

You will get date String which you can store, and that will be sorted string array.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Boobesh Please use this code.

```
let sortedArray = datesArray.sorted { ($0 as! String).localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1 as! String) == .orderedDescending}
```